# Throwing 401 in MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I would like to raise a security exception whenever a user tries to access any area they're not entitled to.  I need more control than the AuthorizeAttribute gives me so in the Action I have this: `throw new HttpException((int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, String.Empty);` which works fine for 404s and 403s. However what I get instead is a 500 error:

> ```
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the
> ```
>
> execution of the current web request.
>   Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where
>   it originated in the code.
>
> ```
> Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException:
> ```

Is there any way to throw a 401 or is it just a case of redirecting the user to a custom 401 view.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help Ardman.  I tried using the HttpUnauthorized ActionResult but decided to redirect the user to a custom 401 error page instead, as the ActionResult just redirects them to the Login page which I didn't really want.